# Multiple react routers in one file

Tags: reactjs

I have two components: Topbar and SideBar. Sidebar works fine, content changes if click links. Here's a code of router for Sidebar:

```
render(
    <Router history={browserHistory}>     
        <Route component={Sidebar}>
            <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/book" component={Book}/>
            <Route path="/car" component={Car}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Now I want a link in a Topbar to change a content. I've just added one more router after the router of the Sidebar:

```
    <Router history={browserHistory}>     
        <Route component={Topbar}>
            <Route path="/add-book" component={AddBook}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('topbar')
```

It does not work. Then I've tried this:

```
var Routes = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
          <Router history={browserHistory}>       
            <Route component={Sidebar}>
            <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/books" component={Book}/>
            <Route path="/cars" component={Car}/>
          </Router>
    )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Routes />, document.getElementById('root'));


var RoutesTop = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <Router history={browserHistory}>       
        <Route component={Topbar}>
            <Route path="/add-books" component={AddBook}/>
        </Route>
      </Router>
    )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<RoutesTop />, document.getElementById('topbar'));
```

It does not work as well. How to make work link in a Topbar?